# Copy/Original printing in Netsuite

Tags: oracle, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to print original first time and copy after the first time printing. I have created a custom field that stored the timestamp of first time printing. So, the template will check first time the field is empty so "original" is printed and the timestamp will stored to the field. Then, when the template is printed after the first time it will check the field, find that there is a content (The timestamp) so it will print copy on the printed template. everything is work fine, buttt when trying to access the advance template of the applied transaction (like: Bill or any) it show an error like below the code!!! What is the issue?

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
*/
define(['N/render','N/record'], function(render,record) {

  function beforeLoad(context) {
    var UserEventType = context.UserEventType;
    var contextType = context.type;
    var newRecord = context.newRecord;
    var newRecordID= context.newRecord.id;
    var currentDate = sysDate(); // returns the date
    var currentTime = timestamp(); // returns the time stamp in HH:MM:SS
    var currentDateAndTime = currentDate + ' ' + currentTime;
    
    
    if (contextType == UserEventType.PRINT) {
      var fieldId = 'custbody_first_print' // fieldId of your custom field / checkbox (or use a datetimestamp)

      var isPrinted = newRecord.getValue({ fieldId: fieldId })
      if (!isPrinted) {
        
      var myRecord = record.load({id: newRecordID , type: newRecord.type}); // in the beforeLoad, editing the newRecord is not allowed, so you need to load the record first, edit and save.

      myRecord.setValue({ fieldId: fieldId, value: currentDateAndTime })
      myRecord.save();    

      }

    }
  }

function sysDate() {
var date = new Date();
var tdate = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // jan = 0
var year = date.getFullYear();
return currentDate = month + '/' + tdate + '/' + year;
}

function timestamp() {
var str = "";

var currentTime = new Date();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
var meridian = "";
if (hours > 12) {
    meridian += "pm";
} else {
    meridian += "am";
}
if (hours > 12) {

    hours = hours - 12;
}
if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
str += hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";

return str + meridian;
}

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad,

    };
});
```

**The Error:** Error during loading transaction for advanced printing Caused by: com.netsuite.suitescript.exception.NLServerSideScriptException: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"load: Missing a required argument: id","stack":["createError(N/error)","beforeLoad(/SuiteScripts/Copy_Original.js:23)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"load: Missing a required argument: id"},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is worked now, check the sol. :
I should add && recId --->(context.newRecord.id)**

```
if (contextType == UserEventType.PRINT && recId) {
      var fieldId = 'custbody_first_print' // fieldId of your custom field / checkbox (or use a datetimestamp)

      var isPrinted = recObj.getValue({ fieldId: fieldId })
      if (!isPrinted) {
        
      var myRecord = record.load({id: recId, type: recObj.type}); // in the beforeLoad, editing the newRecord is not allowed, so you need to load the record first, edit and save.

      myRecord.setValue({ fieldId: fieldId, value: currentDateAndTime })
      myRecord.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the base problem is that you are not passing a record ID to the record.load method.

**A breakdown of the error:**

**What is the Error:** "SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT" (you are missing an argument that it needs in order to execute)

**Where:** "beforeLoad(/SuiteScripts/Copy_Original.js:23)" (the beforeLoad event in your suitescript Copy_Original, on line 23.)

**What argument are you missing:** "load: Missing a required argument: id" (after the : it tells you id)

I would change the names of your variables so they are different from the netsuite names. particularly newRecord, this will eliminate confusion and the possibility of you referencing a netsuite enum when you are trying to use your variable. (I believe that is what is happening here as I am able to get this to work on my record when using the following.)

```
function beforeLoad(context) {
    var UserEventType = context.UserEventType;
    var contextType = context.type;
    var recObj= context.newRecord;
    var recId= recObj.id;
    var currentDate = sysDate(); // returns the date
    var currentTime = timestamp(); // returns the time stamp in HH:MM:SS
    var currentDateAndTime = currentDate + ' ' + currentTime;
    
    
    if (contextType == UserEventType.PRINT) {
      var fieldId = 'custbody_first_print' // fieldId of your custom field / checkbox (or use a datetimestamp)

      var isPrinted = recObj.getValue({ fieldId: fieldId })
      if (!isPrinted) {
        
      var myRecord = record.load({id: recId, type: recObj.type}); // in the beforeLoad, editing the newRecord is not allowed, so you need to load the record first, edit and save.

      myRecord.setValue({ fieldId: fieldId, value: currentDateAndTime })
      myRecord.save();    

      }
```

Comment: I am still getting the error ! The script is work and added the value into the field but when I go to the advance template layout of the applied transaction I got the error.

Comment: To clarify: when you run print with the basic layout it runs correctly?

Comment: My next steps would be to run the log.debug('recId:', recId) before and after entering each control flow statement to see where you are losing the id value. Also if I am understanding your code correctly your control flow statement is not working the way you intend it to. If the field is not undefined or null then it should not enter the part where you are adding the timestamp to your custom field. So really instead of if(!isPrinted) it should be if (isPrinted === undefined) that would then only execute the code to change the value if the field is empty. (Assuming it's a text field)